# Gradle compilation error with lombok after merge

Tags: java, gradle, lombok

After switching branch the compilation failed during my build. Here a snippet:

```
    $ ./gradlew clean build
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 stopped Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

    > Task :compileJava
    C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Repositories\Homepage\Home\src\main\java\com\xxx\project\bootstrap\DatabaseLoader.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
    import static com.xxx.homepage.bootstrap.DataSetupUtil.getUserObject;
    ^
      symbol:   static getUserObject
      location: class DataSetupUtil
    C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Repositories\Homepage\Home\src\main\java\com\xxx\project\bootstrap\DataSetupUtil.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
            user.setEmail(email);
                ^
      symbol:   method setEmail(@lombok.NonNull String)
      location: variable user of type User
    C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Repositories\Homepage\Home\src\main\java\com\xxx\project\bootstrap\DataSetupUtil.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
            user.setUsername(username);
                ^
      symbol:   method setUsername(@lombok.NonNull String)
      location: variable user of type User
    C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Repositories\Homepage\Home\src\main\java\com\xxx\project\bootstrap\DataSetupUtil.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
            user.setName(name);
                ^
      symbol:   method setName(@lombok.NonNull String)
      location: variable user of type User
    C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Repositories\Homepage\Home\src\main\java\com\xxx\project\bootstrap\DataSetupUtil.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
            user.setFirstname(firstname);
```

This is the how my build.gradle looks like:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.5.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.xxx'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "${nexusUrl}/content/groups/public/"
            credentials {
                username "$nexusUsername"
                password "$nexusPassword"
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.9'
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '28.2-jre'

    compile group: 'org.thymeleaf.extras', name: 'thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5', version: '3.0.4.RELEASE'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}
```

It's weird, because before switching the branch and before merging everthing worked fine. Has anyone an idea what the reason could be for this compilation problem? Gradle version is 6.2.2`. I also tried to delete the cache under C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\6.2.2
But also this didn't help.

Here the classes that aren't recognized:

```
import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Version
    private Integer version;

    @NonNull
    @Size(min = 8, max = 20)
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, name="USERNAME")
    private String username;

    @NonNull
    @Size(min = 8, max = 30)
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, name="EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @NonNull
    @Column(length = 100, name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;

    @NonNull
    @Column(nullable = false, name="ENABLED")
    private boolean enabled;

    @Size(min = 3, max = 20)
    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @Size(min = 3, max = 20)
    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name="DATE_OF_BIRTH")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    @Size(min = 3, max = 20)
    @Column(name="CITY")
    private String city;

    @Size(min = 3, max = 30)
    @Column(name = "COUNTRY")
    private String country;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    public void addRole(Role role) {
        roles.add(role);
    }

    public void addRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        roles.forEach(this::addRole);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        //map roles to GrantedAuthorities:
        return roles.stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And the Util Class:

```
import com.rajic.homepage.domain.Role;
import com.rajic.homepage.domain.User;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.experimental.UtilityClass;

import java.util.Date;

@UtilityClass
public class DataSetupUtil {

    public User getUserObject(@NonNull String email, @NonNull String username,
                              @NonNull String password, @NonNull String name, @NonNull String firstname,
                              @NonNull String city, @NonNull String country, @NonNull Date dateOfBirth, Role...roles) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setUsername(username);
        user.setName(name);
        user.setFirstname(firstname);
        user.setPassword(password);
        user.setCity(city);
        user.setCountry(country);
        user.setDateOfBirth(dateOfBirth);
        user.setEnabled(true);
        for (int i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
            user.addRole(roles[i]);
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt that it's a gradle issue. Are you statically importing a Lombok-generated method? That won't work in many cases. Try a static * import instead.

Comment: Hmmm...But it worked the whole time. And now it doesn't work without changing anything on these classes. And the sense of a UtilityClass is to use it static or am I wrong? I just added the classes to the question. But I think actually the classes are okay.

Comment: have you upgraded gradle now ?

Comment: I tried several versions 'til 6.2.2. All failed.

Comment: You can statically import a `@UtilityClass`, but you must use the star form: `import static com.xxx.homepage.bootstrap.DataSetupUtil.*;`

Comment: omg. you're right! I thought it is a gradle issues cause all lombok methods had errors. But with this fix the build is successful. It seems like the merge changed the import from star to the method directly. You're are my hero. @Jahn Rieke  If you post you're comment as an answer I mark it as solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static imports of single members ("non-star form") often cause problems when importing lombok-processed classes.

The workaround is to use the star (*) form of the static import:

```
import static com.xxx.homepage.bootstrap.DataSetupUtil.*;
```

The [lombok documentation for `@UtilityClass`](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/UtilityClass#small-print) also mentions this in the small print:

> Due to a peculiar way javac processes static imports, trying to do a non-star static import of any of the members of a `@UtilityClass` won't work. Either use a star static import: `import static TypeMarkedWithUtilityClass.*;` or don't statically import any of the members.